# Consistency in arg routes in symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm a beginner in Symfony2 and I'm just wondering if the consistency of args has to be done myself in the controller or if there is a mechanism i don't know of

let's take a example:

i have a route like /company/id/user/id to display some information for the user

i have tried manually to change id for either company or user and there is no error if the user is not from the company ?!

Do i have to check in the controller displayUserAction if user and company are bound ?

```
/**
 * @Route("/company/{company_id}/user/{site_id}")
 * @ParamConverter("company", class="MyModel\Company", options={"mapping": {"company_id": "id"}})
 * @ParamConverter("site", class="MyModel\User", options={"mapping": {"site_id": "id"}})
 */
public function displayUserAction(Company $company, User $user)
{
..
}

routing.yml
user_info:
path:     /company/{company_id}/user/{site_id}
defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:displayUser }
```

Edit:
I've found another way : map using several criteria

```
/**
 * @Route("/company/{company_id}/user/{site_id}")
 * @ParamConverter("company", class="MyModel\Company", options={"mapping": {"company_id": "id"}})
 * @ParamConverter("site", class="MyModel\User", options={"mapping": {"site_id": "id", "company_id":"company"}})
 */
public function displayUserAction(Company $company, User $user)
{
..
}
```

Comment: Yep.  As far as the param converter goes, all you asked for was a company and a user.  It has no idea you wanted some additional validation to be done.

Comment: you could write your custom param converter for this task or check in the controller

Comment: @Matteo how can i write param converter for this ?

Comment: @jolan you can find a good tutorial about howto write a custom param converter [here](https://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/symfony2-custom-paramconverter). Hope this help

Comment: @matteo tx help me a lot

Comment: Instead of writing a custom ParamConverter, consider writing an authorization voter that determines if the fetched user belongs to the company. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: @gerry yes i've thought of that too. Btw I have changed my routes to be able to use a voter simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-order the arguments in the Action all you like. Symfony is smart enough to match the arguments - but you should keep the naming somewhat consistent - which you have done anyway. Symfony will match `{company_id}` in your route to `$company` in your Action for example no matter the order you place them in.

In your route, both arguments are required for the route to match. So the route will only match work if both arguments are bound.

In your Action, you would need to check the User belongs to the Company. The architecture of the Route and the Action don't care if the 2 entities are related, they only care that a value has been supplied.